# How to get "pip wheel" to use local installs

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I'm trying to get `pip wheel .` to build a .whl when in a directory with `setup.py`.  I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement foo (from mymodule)
```

However, if I do `pip list` I see the package is installed

```
Package      Version
-----------  --------
foo          1.0.0
```

How do I get `pip wheel` to use an (internal) dependency that is already installed in the environment instead of trying to fetch it from a remote location?

EDIT:  Also, why does it even care if the dependencies are installed or not? It's just creating the package, not installing or including those deps, so why would it matter  if the deps are available?

Comment: run it with `--no-deps` and then you don't need to wheel the dependencies -- or use `python -m build` (you'll need to install it) which is the new recommended way I guess

Comment: Where do you see the recommendation to use `build`?

Comment: the pip docs for example: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_wheel/#differences-to-build